# VB.net decoding MP3 file from JSON Byte array

Tags: android, json, vb.net, xmpp

Bit of an odd one!

I've got a load of Android (4.4.2) devices running some custom delivery tracking software (which I wrote) - One of the features is to record a voice report and have it send via mobile networks. It's usually all working brilliantly, but I've been bought some new devices and suddenly all of the voice recordings are coming in at 50kb in size and 0:00 length.

Now, each packet is encoded with JSON and sent via XMPP (through OpenFire) to an XMPP bot client written in VB.NET (using jabber) - A sample packet is shown below (I've omitted some, due to it's length, but you'll get the general idea):

```
    {"mMessageType":{"batteryInfo":{"mHealth":2,"mLevel":84,
"mPlugged":2,"mStatus":2,"mTemp":318},"content":"VOICE",
"mType":"VOICE","userId":406},"mPayload":{"data":[0,0,0,24,
102,116,121,112,51,103,112,52,0,0,0,0,105,115,111,109,51,103,
112,52,0,0,5,8,109,111,111,118,0,0,0,108,109,118,104,100,0,
0,0,0,-49,-68,-88,-64,-49,-68,-88,-64,0,0,3,-24,0,0,14,36,0,
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,27,117,100,116,97,
0,0,0,19,97,117,116,104,0,0,0,0,21,-57,76,71,69,0,47,0,0,4,
121,116,114,97,107,0,0,0,92,116,107,104,100,0,0,0,7,-49,-68,
-88,-64,-49,-68,-88,-64,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,36,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,21,
109,100,105,97,0,0,0,32,109,100,104,100,0,0,0,0,-49,-68,-88,
-64,-49,-68,-88,-64,0,0,31,64,0,0,113,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,44,
104,100,108,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,115,111,117,110,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,83,111,117,110,100,72,97,110,100,108,101,0,0,0,
3,-63,109,105,110,102,0,0,0,16,115,109,104,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,36,100,105,110,102,0,0,0,28,100,114,101,102,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,12,117,114,108,32,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,-123,115,
116,98,108,0,0,0,69,115,116,115,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
53,115,97,109,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,16,
0,0,0,0,31,64,0,0,0,0,0,17,100,97,109,114,32,32,32,0,0,
-125,-1,0,1,0,0,0,32,115,116,116,115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,-96,0,0,0,-76,0,0,0,-96,0,0,2,-24,115,116,115,122,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-75,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,
0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,
... Removed for sanity sake
,96],"timestamp":"","path":"/storage/emulated/0/audio_85344_1.3gp",
"reportedFully":0,"deliverySiteId":85344,"id":17,"reported":1}}
```

And this is fed into my .NET client here:

```
 Public Sub ProcessVoiceMessage(ByVal o As Message)
    Dim messageObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Transaction)(o.Body)

    ' Incoming Message
    WriteToLog(o.From.User & "/" & o.From.Resource, "VOICE Transaction >> Device Record ID: " &
               messageObject.mPayload("id") & " - for DeliveryID: " & messageObject.mPayload("deliverySiteId"))
    Dim i As Long = 0
    Dim audioBytes(1024 * 50) As Byte

    For Each jval As JValue In messageObject.mPayload("data")
        Dim byteseses(1024 * 2) As Byte
        byteseses = BitConverter.GetBytes(jval.Value)
        audioBytes(i) = byteseses(0)
        i += 1
    Next

    Dim fn As String = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath, IO.Path.GetTempFileName & ".mp3")
    File.WriteAllBytes(fn, audioBytes)

    ' See if this payload is linked to a delivery drop, or that of a device level recording 
    ' (in which case, we save against the device object itself)
    If (CLng(messageObject.mPayload("deliverySiteId")) > 0) Then
        Dim ds As New DeliverySite(CLng(messageObject.mPayload("deliverySiteId")))
        ds.AddDocument(fn, GlobalStoreDocument.eAttachmentType.Upload, GlobalStoreDocument.eDocumentType.PODVoice, Nothing, ds.ParentDelivery.Driver.ID)


        Dim mt As New MessageType(MessageType.Type.CONFIRMATION)
        Dim conf As New Confirmation(ConfirmationStatus.ALL_OK,
                "VOICE",
                "GEE_THANKS!",
                messageObject.mPayload("id"))
        SendMessage(MakeTransactionPacket(mt, conf, o.From.Bare))

        ds.Dispose()
        ds = Nothing

        mt = Nothing
        conf = Nothing
    Else
        ' Device level voice recording
        Dim d As New Device(o.From.User)
        d.AddDocument(fn, GlobalStoreDocument.eAttachmentType.Upload, GlobalStoreDocument.eDocumentType.PODVoice, Nothing, CLng(messageObject.mMessageType("userId")))


        Dim mt As New MessageType(MessageType.Type.CONFIRMATION)
        Dim conf As New Confirmation(ConfirmationStatus.ALL_OK,
                "VOICE",
                "GEE_THANKS!",
                messageObject.mPayload("id"))
        SendMessage(MakeTransactionPacket(mt, conf, o.From.Bare))

        d.Dispose()
        d = Nothing

        mt = Nothing
        conf = Nothing
    End If

    IO.File.Delete(fn)
    messageObject = Nothing
    audioBytes = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now as I said previously, it was working, so I immediately started hacking away at it like a crazed monkey on crack... (Worry not, I'm all SVN'd up!) It's clearly a problem with the decoding of the byte values from JSON array, and thus the conversion back into binary format, but I can't fathom it.

** edit **
Should really add all of the Android code too ! MediaRecorder for the voice reports:

```
    public void startRecording() 
    {       
        ++voiceRecordingNumber;

        filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();//.getAbsolutePath();
        if(this.d != null)
        {
            // FOR DELIVERY RECORDING OF PROOF //
            filename += String.format("/audio_%s_%d.%s", this.d.getDeliveryId(), voiceRecordingNumber, Constants.VOICE_EXT);
        }
        else
        {
            // FOR HOME SCREEN RECORDING OF PROOF //
            filename += String.format("/audio_PROOF_%s.%s", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), Constants.VOICE_EXT);
        }

        Log.i("VoiceRecorder", "Startup");      

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);                 // Default audio source
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);         // 3GPP Media File
        recorder.setOutputFile(filename);                                       // Output filename
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);            // audio codec
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(Constants.SAMPLERATES_MPEG1_L3[0]);       // Sample rate

        try 
        {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("VoiceRecorder","Am prepared");       
        recorder.start();
    }
```

And the background process that sends all data via xmpp:

```
        // Get a list of all voice recordings to send
        List<AudioRecording> audios = new AudioRecording().getAllRecords();
        for(AudioRecording a : audios)
        {
            // Process the audio files on local storage for sending over the wire
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            File audioFile = new File(a.getPath());
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(audioFile);
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int read;

            try
            {
                while((read = is.read(b)) >= 0)
                {
                    baos.write(b, 0, read);
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try 
                {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {           
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            a.setData(data);

            Log.i("BGCP", "Processing voice transaction (" + a.getId() + "/" + a.getDeliverySiteId() + ")");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundXmppConnector.class);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGEDATA", new Gson().toJson(
                Utility.makeTransaction(getApplicationContext(),
                MessageType.Type.VOICE,
                a)));

            if(mService.sendMessage(intent))
            {
                Log.i("BGCP", "Voice transaction (" + a.getId() + "/" + a.getDeliverySiteId() + ") HAS been reported");
                a.setReported(1);
                a.updateRecord();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("BGCP", "Voice transaction (" + a.getId() + "/" + a.getDeliverySiteId() + ") HAS NOT been reported");
                // Ignore the updating of this record, it'll get sent out when we spin in 1 minute
            }

            b = null;           
            is = null;
            data = null;
            baos = null;
            intent = null;
            audioFile = null;
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by just converting the byte array to a Base64 String and sent it across. The decoding is now far easier:

```
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = GetVoiceRecordingFromString(messageObject.mPayload("dataAsString"))
    File.WriteAllBytes(fn, ms.ToArray())
```

And the method

```
    Public Function GetVoiceRecordingFromString(ByVal s As String) As MemoryStream
    If s = "" Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim b As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(s)
    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(b, 0, b.Length)
        ms.Write(b, 0, b.Length)

        Return ms
    End Using
End Function
```